# Override stubborn CSS with Greasemonkey, for calculated cells?

Tags: jquery, css, html-table, greasemonkey

I'm creating a Greasemonkey script for [**this page**](http://www.goal.com/en-us/results-standings/69/serie-a/table).

What I would like to do is to change all the values of the games won, drawn and lost to their percentage score and the highlight the *DRAWN* cells (or rows) which have a percentage score equal or over 70% for the home or away scores.

I managed to do the first part but I'm having a lot of troubles trying to highlight a cell or a row.

First I tried this code

```
$('.teamStandings tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().css('backgroundColor', '#EFEF00');
});
```

Which actually selected all the rows; but I wasn't able to see any difference until I disabled this part of the code from the CSS via *Firebug*:

```
.teamStandings tr.rowOne td {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

So I would like to get this working, overriding the original CSS every time I browse the page and get working a more complicated scheme:

```
$('.teamStandings tbody tr').each(function() {
  var x1=parseInt($cells.eq(8).text(),10) ;
  var x2=parseInt($cells.eq(9).text(),10) ;
  var x3=parseInt($cells.eq(10).text(),10) ;

  var y1=parseInt($cells.eq(11).text(),10) ;
  var y2=parseInt($cells.eq(12).text(),10) ;
  var y3=parseInt($cells.eq(13).text(),10) ;      


  if ((x2/(x1+x2+x3))*100 >= 70) or (y2/(y1+y2+y3))*100 >= 70)
      $(this).parent().css('backgroundColor', '#EFEF00');
});
```

Which sadly doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

1. The first code block is setting the `backgroundColor` of the **`tbody`** (multiple times), not any row or cell.
2. The `.teamStandings tr.rowOne td`, and similar styles, override the first code block because they have a higher [*Specificity*](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/).
3. The second code block has the same problem as the first.
   **Additionally:**
4. It uses `$cells` without ever defining it!
5. The `if()` has a syntax error; `or` is not a valid operator.
6. Use meaningful variable names, and use variables instead of "magic numbers" (`70`).

Putting it all together, this code highlights the *Drawn* cells where more than 70% of the games were draws:

```
var highlightPercent    = 70;

$('.teamStandings tr').each ( function () {
    var columns     = $(this).find ('td');

    var homeWon     = parseInt (columns.eq( 8).text(), 10) ;
    var homeDraw    = parseInt (columns.eq( 9).text(), 10) ;
    var homeLoss    = parseInt (columns.eq(10).text(), 10) ;

    var awayWon     = parseInt (columns.eq(11).text(), 10) ;
    var awayDraw    = parseInt (columns.eq(12).text(), 10) ;
    var awayLoss    = parseInt (columns.eq(13).text(), 10) ;

    if (homeDraw * 100 / (homeWon + homeDraw + homeLoss)  >= highlightPercent) {
        //-- To highlight the whole row, uncomment the next line.
        //columns.css ('backgroundColor', 'pink');
        columns.eq( 9).css ('backgroundColor', '#EFEF00');
    }

    if (awayDraw * 100 / (awayWon + awayDraw + awayLoss)  >= highlightPercent) {
        //-- To highlight the whole row, uncomment the next line.
        //columns.css ('backgroundColor', 'pink');
        columns.eq(12).css ('backgroundColor', '#EFEF00');
    }
} );
```

Currently, on [the sample page](http://www.goal.com/en-us/results-standings/69/serie-a/table), the only applicable result is *Torino*, away games.

---

PS:  You would place/run this code **before the code that converts values to percentages**, which you said was working and did not show.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you've set the `background-color` for the `tr` element.
While the CSS on the page, is setting the `background-color` for the `td` elements within the tr.

So you should be targeting the same `td` elements instead of `tr` element

```
$('.teamStandings tbody tr td').each(function() {
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#EFEF00');
});
```

In your second code block

```
if ((x2/(x1+x2+x3))*100 >= 70) or (y2/(y1+y2+y3))*100 >= 70)
```

In the if condition, is the `or` keyword a typo?

Comment: Close, but you need to delete the `.parent()` part.